# Why is systemd not bringing down dependencies?

Tags: linux, systemd

I have created a systemd service file, whose task is nothing, but just to bring up other services, and bring them down as well.

Since it does nothing, other than bringing up other services, i have put an echo to `ExecStart` and `ExecStop`.

The issue is, i can see the dependencies are brought up fine when i invoke `service <myService> start`, but they are not stopped when i call `service <myService> stop`. Even using `BindsTo` does not work.

Here is my service configuration file:

```
[Unit]
Description=Starts the DCCA index software
Requires=mysql.service ifmFuseHandler.service
After=mysql.service ifmFuseHandler.service
BindsTo=mysql.service ifmFuseHandler.service

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/bin/sh -c "echo 'Index started'"
ExecStop=/bin/sh -c "echo 'Index stopped'"

# Execute pre and post scripts as root
PermissionsStartOnly=true
Restart=on-failure

TimeoutSec=600
Type=forking
RemainAfterExit=yes
```

**Solution:**
As suggested by `@grawity` i created a .target file called index-start.target as below:

```
[Unit]
Description=Starts the DCCA index software
Requires=mysql.service ifmFuseHandler.service
After=mysql.service ifmFuseHandler.service
BindsTo=mysql.service ifmFuseHandler.service

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

And a service file called index.service:

```
[Unit]
Description=Starts the DCCA index software
Requires=index-start.target
After=index-start.target

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target index-start.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/bin/true
ExecStop=/bin/sh -c "echo 'Index stopped'"

# Execute pre and post scripts as root
PermissionsStartOnly=true
#Restart=on-failure (Commented as does not work with type=oneshot)

TimeoutSec=600
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=yes
```

And when invoked, `service index start` it starts the dependencies and `service index stop` it stops the dependencies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you really should use a [`.target`](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.target.html) here, not a dummy service. (And for dummy services, `Type=oneshot` and `ExecStart=/bin/true` would be more fitting than `forking`.)

`BindsTo=` (and `PartOf=`) needs to be used in the *opposite* direction – it works just like `Requires=` in that *this* unit is stopped if the *listed* units disappear. So you need to add it to mysql.service and ifmFuseHandler.service instead. (Use drop-ins to extend the default mysql.service.)

Comment: I just tried it once as-is using `type=oneshot` but it does not bring down the dependencies. I tried using `ExecStop=/bin/false` but looks like it does not exist, like `/bin/true` does. Pardon my ignorance, but is there a way out to stop it, using `type=oneshot` which you mentioned? Although, i wish to make it full-proof using the `target` later, but just for hands-on sake tried it.

Comment: I tried using the `.target` but the issue is, there is no way to manually start or stop the service using the `service xxxx start` or `service xxxx stop`, which is also a required part, in addition to starting at boot time. Any way out?

Comment: I created a .target file, as u indicated, and the same is edited and posted above. It works as expected, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to your question/solution I got a good solution for me I'd like to share.
My requirement is to have a `allservices.target` which starts/stops/restarts `srv1.service`, `srv2.service`, and `srv3.service`.

A requirement is, that I could stop e.g. `srv1.service` and the other services and the target are still running after that.

The Key is to have the services in the `Wants` directive in the `.target` and in the srv*.services the `PartOf=allservices.target`

**allservices.target**

```
[Unit]
Description=start allservices
Wants=syslog.target network.target srv1.service srv2.service srv3.service 
After=network.target
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

**srv1.service**

```
[Unit]
Description=run srv1.service
Wants=syslog.target network.target
PartOf=allservices.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/path/to/bin/start
ExecStop=/bin/kill $MAINPID
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=allservices.target
```

Like this after I hit `systemctl start allservices.target` srv1-srv3 are started, the same with `stop` and `restart`. 
And if I run `systemctl stop srv1.service` the other services and the target are still running.